Does FTC law apply to international merchants?
The FTC, under 16 CFR Part 435, provides certain requirements for remotely-purchased goods.
Do these laws apply if an international seller sells to someone in the US (in particular, to a seller in the UK)? What about a US seller selling to someone outside the US?

This issue is addressed at length in a 1989 law review article. The statute authorizing the FTC regulations expressly grants the FTC authority of international commerce with the U.S.
So, for the most part, the question is one of the ability of the FTC to assert personal jurisdiction over a party, rather than its subject-matter jurisdiction, which is generally present.
A U.S. seller is going to be subject to FTC jurisdiction, and hence, its regulations, even when selling to a buyer outside the United States.
In the case of a non-U.S. seller selling to a U.S. based buyer, this is going to boil down to the U.S. constitutional law test for personal jurisdiction.
In the simple case, where the seller has no presence in the U.S. other than mail, telecommunications, the Internet, and shipping goods via common carriers and has no employees or agents in the U.S., this boils down to the constitutional test for specific personal jurisdiction. This is largely a matter of whether the non-U.S. seller has directed its activities towards the U.S. and purposefully availed itself of U.S. law.
Basically, this means that ads on the Internet or in non-U.S. media that aren't specifically targeted at U.S. customers are not going to subject the non-U.S. seller to false advertising laws. But, the non-U.S. seller will be subject to U.S. laws, including FTC regulations in connection with individual transactions that the seller knows involve a U.S. shipping destination.
Thus, a U.K. seller knowing that the are selling a good to someone in the U.S. are subject (in the view of the FTC) to FTC regulations in that particular transaction, but only to FTC advertising rules in connection with ads somehow targeted at U.S. buyers. Of course, the FTC may need cooperation from U.K. officials to do so, if there are no U.S. assets of the U.K. seller that can be seized as a penalty for a violation.
And, since the U.K. has left the E.U., with whom the U.S. had an FTC enforcement cooperation treaty, and the U.S. has not yet entered into a similar treaty with the U.K., whether the U.K. government and courts will cooperate is a question of U.K. law upon which I am not qualified to say anything meaningful without much more research.
A U.S. buyer selling to someone outside the U.S. will usually also be subject to the FTC rules.
It is, of course, more complicated than that. But, this is the general rule and the gist of how jurisdiction is allocated.

You mention "false advertising rules" a lot, but does that include 16 CFR Part 435, particularly the rules described in the link in the Question?
